# sample across a list of character vectors

Tags: r

**Problem**

I want to replace the phrase `"COMPARTMENT_START"` with the phrase xy where the "y" part is a sampled number from my dataframe

**Input**

```
structure(list(report = c("COMPARTMENT_START duod biospies taken WritePathReport NUMBER OF BIOPSIES: biopsied x8 COMPARTMENT_END\", \"COMPARTMENT_START duod biospies taken", 
"COMPARTMENT_START oesophagus biospies taken WritePathReport NUMBER OF BIOPSIES: character(0) COMPARTMENT_END\", \"COMPARTMENT_START duod biospies taken", 
"\", \"COMPARTMENT_START duod biospies taken", "COMPARTMENT_START duod biospies taken"
)), .Names = "report", row.names = 979:982, class = "data.frame")
```

**The output should be:**

```
x3 duod biospies taken WritePathReport NUMBER OF BIOPSIES: biopsied x8 COMPARTMENT_END", "x5 duod biospies taken
x2 oesophagus biospies taken WritePathReport NUMBER OF BIOPSIES: character(0) COMPARTMENT_END", "x1 duod biospies taken                                                                                                            ", "x1 duod biospies taken                                                                                                                 x3x duod biospies taken
```

**I have tried:**

```
lapply(dff3$report,function(x) paste(gsub("COMPARTMENT_START",paste0("x"sample(3:10,1)),x)))
```

but I get:

```
"x8 duod biospies taken WritePathReport NUMBER OF BIOPSIES: biopsied x8 COMPARTMENT_END\", \"x8 duod biospies taken"    
"x3 oesophagus biospies taken WritePathReport NUMBER OF BIOPSIES: character(0) COMPARTMENT_END\", \"x3 duod biospies taken"
"\", \"x5 duod biospies taken"    
"x5 duod biospies taken"
```

How can I sample to get different numbers between elements of the vector in the list and then output back as a dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
df1$report <- gsubfn("(COMPARTMENT_START)",
            function(x) paste0("x", sample(3:10, 1)), df1$report)
df1$report
#[1] "x7 duod biospies taken WritePathReport NUMBER OF BIOPSIES: biopsied x8 COMPARTMENT_END\", \"x6 duod biospies taken"        
#[2] "x10 oesophagus biospies taken WritePathReport NUMBER OF BIOPSIES: character(0) COMPARTMENT_END\", \"x9 duod biospies taken"
#[3] "\", \"x8 duod biospies taken"                                                                                              
#[4] "x10 duod biospies taken"
```